# Ionic 2.2.3 Background Color not Changing on New Page in SCSS File

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, background-color

I created a new page in Ionic 2.2.3, using `ionic -g page pagename`. I then switched it to the root page and got it all working. The problem is that when I edit it's `.scss` file to change the background color, it doesn't change the background color, even if I stop the `ionic serve` and rerun it.

pagename.scss:

```
page-pagename {
  background: #DD1155;
}
```

After doing a lot of Googling, I saw people mention `app.core.scss` under the `app/theme` folder, but this folder structure doesn't exist under the new Ionic 2.2.3 version. Does anyone know how to change the background color in Ionic 2.2.3 using the `.scss` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by setting the background color to the `scroll-content` class:

```
page-pagename {
  .scroll-content {
    background: #DD1155;
  }
}
```